# How to find beacon major and minor number using RxBle

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java, rxandroidble

I'm having trouble finding the major and minor number of a bluetooth beacon using RxBle. Any help would be appreciated. I've tried this

```
rxBleClient = ProxiApplication.getRxBleClient(this)
    scanDisposable = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
            ScanSettings.Builder()
                    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                    .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                    .build(),
            ScanFilter.Builder()
                    .build()
    ).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doFinally(this::dispose)
            .subscribe({
                Log.v("MainActivity", "scan results: ${it}"]
            }, {
                Log.v("MainActivity", "error: $it")
            })
```

Comment: What have you tried till now? Please share your code

Comment: I've tried this, I tried debugging the results, but can't seem to find anything

Comment: Seems weird as this code works just fine on my end. Is your app in foreground?

Comment: It's not that It doesn't work. I just entirely don't know how to find the major and minor number

Comment: I do not see any attempt to parse the results you get to beacon data in the code you have posted. Have you tried to [search google](https://www.google.pl/search?q=android+beacon+scan) how to parse advertisements to find beacons? The [second result](https://medium.com/@eliaslecomte/scan-for-i-beacons-on-android-cf97ff532678) points to some code that does [exactly that](https://github.com/inthepocket/ibeacon-scanner-android/blob/1.2.1/ibeaconscanner/src/main/java/mobi/inthepocket/android/beacons/ibeaconscanner/ScannerScanCallback.java#L73) — you can try it out